# Task Control Flow

Tags: asynchronous, task

I've been working with the task and async/await constructs for a couple of days and the flow sometimes throws me off. Maybe because I'm thinking about it in a synchronous manner. I have the following piece of code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Call a async method with no result from non-async method....!");

        Task myTask = DoSomethingAsync();
        myTask.Wait();
        myTask.ContinueWith(t => {
            Console.WriteLine("Inside continuation.");
        });

        Console.WriteLine("Program completed...");

        Console.WriteLine("Completed...");
    }
    static async Task DoSomethingAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Inside DoSomething; no return value.");
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        Console.WriteLine("DoSomething method is completed...");
    }
```

My problem is that when Wait is called I'm assuming that the compiler is waiting for my DoSomethingAsync method to complete and then the continuation would get executed; however, the continuation isn't executed until after the 'Program is Completed' and 'Completed' text is printed to the screen. When running in debug mode it looks like the debugger comes back to the continuation once the DoSomethingAsync method has completed; but actually it doesn't. What's going on? Is it due to starting up another task? If so, why isn't the task started after the Wait?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By placing a Wait on the continuation so that the code now reads as

```
  myTask.ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Inside continuation.");
        }).Wait();
```

This will now allow the continuation to complete before calling that the program completed.